# Luigi Programmatic Configuration

Tags: python-3.x, luigi

I was using a configuration file similar to the following for my `luigi` workflows:

```
# Luigi logging configuration
[logging]
version = 1
disable_existing_loggers = false

[logging.formatters.simple]
format = "{levelname:8} {asctime} {module}:{lineno} {message}"
style = "{"
datefmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

# Luigi contrib configurations
[postgres]
marker-table="luigi_table_updates"
```

And then invoking `luigi` from the command like like this:

```sh
LUIGI_CONFIG_PATH='path/to/luigi.toml' luigi ...
```

However, I would like to programmatically invoke my workflows. I can do this using the `luigi.build` method; however, I tried passing in my config path like this:

```py
luigi.build(my_tasks, local_scheduler=True, LUIGI_CONFIG_PATH='path/to/luigi.toml')
```

And got the following error:

```
luigi.parameter.UnknownParameterException: core[args=(), kwargs={'local_scheduler': True, 'LUIGI_CONFIG_PATH': 'path/to/luigi.toml', 'no_lock': True}]: unknown parameter LUIGI_CONFIG_PATH
```

I assumed using it as a kwarg would load it into the environment (`luigi.build`s `env_params`) similar to how `local_scheduler` is loaded.

So, my question is, what is the appropriate way to configure `luigi` programmatically?

Answer (score 5):

I figured this out; not sure if there's a better way but I found a method call that loads the config:

```py
import luigi

luigi.configuration.add_config_path('path/to/my-config.cfg')
```

I did not found a way to specify the parser, however, and after reading the the source I'm not sure its possible at the moment. So, I just switched from TOML to cfg and all was well.